# Create jQuery slider to have rating system from 1 to 10

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to create a slider that has a rating system that looks like the one in the image (colours don't need to match, just the numbers).

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FmD7D.jpg]

I know I should use the

```
$("#slider").slider();
```

bit, like shown here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider, but I don't really understand how to build a min (0,5 or 1), max (10) and steps (0,5 or 1) in it. Also, after that, I have a button

```
<a href="#linkToOtherPage" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Save</a>
```

And when it is clicked, I want it to show an alert that the selected rating is saved.
Anyone know how to do it?

#### edit

Just discovered that jquery-mobile handles the sliders in another way. And I'm using jQuery-mobile in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I needed to use the jQuery-mobile slider function. Used this now:

```
        <input type="range" name="slider-mini" id="slider-mini" value="5" min="1" max="10" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" />
        <script>
          function saveSlider() {
            var value = $( "#slider-mini" ).val();
            alert ("You have selected the value: " + value);
          }

        </script>
```

It has steps of instead of 0,5, but that's ok for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#slider").slider({ max: 10, min: 1, step: 0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but from the documentation you referenced, it looks like this should do the trick:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider( { min: 0.5,
                           max: 10,
                           step: 0.5,
                           value: 5 } );
```

To display the value from the slider, and display it in an alert, try the following:

```
<script>

  function saveSlider() {
    var value = $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value" );
    alert ("you have selected the value " + value);
  }

</script>

<input type="button" value="click me" onClick="saveSlider();" />
```

Comment: Well, it should show a bar, like the image in the post. And then someone can slide it to a number (for example '8'). Then the person clicks 'Save' and it gives an alert box saying 'Your rating of 8 has been saved'

Comment: Also, do you know how I show this slider? Something like this?   `<select name="slider" id="slider" data-role="slider">
   </select>`

Comment: sure, but saved to where?  are you asking for code to post the selected value to a server somewhere, or are you just wanting an alert that demonstrates how to demonstrate the number selected by the slider?

Comment: Just an alert should do for now. Best would be to save it to localStorage, but first I want it to demonstrate that the slider works.

Comment: check out the 'View Source' tab on the documentation page.  with the selector code above, all you need is a '<div id="slider"></div>'.

Comment: i've updated my answer to show how to display the slider value in an alert.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now it does indeed show an alert, but the value stays the same (5), whatever place I put the slider.

Comment: do you know how I can make it take the value I selected?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery-mobile, so I'm not sure what to tell you.   I modified the example code from the documentation link above to include the bits I told you, and it works fine for me.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/28PH3/

Comment: It was my mistake that I didn't see I was using jQuery-mobile. Your answer solves the problem for jQuery tho, so thanks for that. I'm sure it'll be helpful for someone. :)